# Blender bevel selected edge of a default cube with Python

Tags: python, default, blender, cube, modifier

I'd like to bevel a single edge of a default cube with Python in Blender 3.0. I need to select two vertices of an edge to select the edge and bevel it. This is proving quite difficult.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.active_object  # Get selected object

epsilon = 1e-5  # Threshold to account for floating point precision

if obj:
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')  # Go into edit mode
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="EDGE")  # Switch to edge select mode

   
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)  # Create bmesh object for easy mesh evaluation
    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    obj.data.polygons[2].select = True
    for e in bm.edges:  # Check all edges
    
        if e.index  == 0:
            print ("abc")
            first_pos = e.verts[0].co  # Get first vert position of this edge
            other_pos = e.verts[1].co  # Get second vert position of this edge

            e.select_set(abs(first_pos.x - other_pos.x) <= epsilon and abs(first_pos.y - other_pos.y) <= epsilon)
        
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(obj.data)  # Update the mesh in edit mode
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_set_active(modifier="Bevel")
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BEVEL')

    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Bevel"].segments = 10
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Bevel"].width = 0.37
```

[image]

I can select the whole cube and all the edges but not a specific edge.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to select one edge to bevel and leave the rest unchanged.

You can do this by selecting the “Weight” limit method in the bevel modifier.  In this method,
each edge in your mesh has a “Bevel Weight”  which is used to multiply the size of your bevel on that edge. So if the Bevel Weight on an edge is 0 – no bevel on that edge; if Bevel Weight is 1, then you get a full bevel.

The Bevel Weight is normally set to 0 on all edges in a new mesh. It can be changed
(in Edit mode)  by selecting  the edges you want to bevel, then

```
 “Edge” menu -  “ Edge_Bevel_Weights” :     1
```

This sets the weight to 1 on the edge (or edges) you want to bevel.

In Python, your  script  should be modified by changing your code as follows

```
 # To use this script:
 #    1)  Open Blender new file   (default cube is already loaded and selected)
 #    2)  go to "Scripting" windows arrangement
 #    3)  load this script
 #    4)  Edit mode - select "Vertex" mode
 #    5)  Deselect all vertices  <Alt>A
 #    6)  Select vertices at both ends of edge to be bevelled
 #    7)  Run script

import bpy
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="EDGE")  # Switch to edge select mode 

bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BEVEL')    # add a new bevel modifier 
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Bevel"].limit_method = 'WEIGHT'     # change its limit method to "weight"
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Bevel"].offset_type = 'WIDTH'
    
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Bevel"].segments = 10
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Bevel"].width = 0.37
 
bpy.ops.transform.edge_bevelweight(value=1)
```

[image]

Finally, I found the following article on Blender  Bevels to be very useful:
“How to solve bevel problems in Blender”    (Erik Selin):
[https://artisticrender.com/how-to-solve-bevel-problems-in-blender/#:~:text=The%20most%20common%20issue%20when,the%20tools%20or%20bad%20geometry](https://artisticrender.com/how-to-solve-bevel-problems-in-blender/#:%7E:text=The%20most%20common%20issue%20when,the%20tools%20or%20bad%20geometry).

Comment: To Suraj Rao: Many thanks for tidying my contribution - it is now as I intended! Thank you.

Comment: This is great thanks guys for this. Can't wait to try it. Just can't right now but I will try the weighting

Comment: So how could you select the edge in script? And bevel that. I can select in the GUI and the edge is white. But when you select an edge in script it becomes orange. Is that the difference between select and activate and what is deselect? Thanks

Comment: # Previous code should have deselected all edges not to be bevelled, selected those that do want bevelled   but how?

Comment: I have edited my original answer to what  (I hope) gives a more complete answer to  what I now think is your question.  Also: your understanding between selected (orange) and active (white) edges is correct.  To deselect an edge means to make the edge "not selected".